Derivation of the Noether current (Gauss law operator) in anomalous chiral gauge theory
I am reading Fujikawa-Suzuki's Path Integrals and Quantum Anomalies, §6.3. The Lagrangian I am looking at is
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4g^2}\left(\partial_\mu L_\nu^a-\partial_{\nu}L_\mu^a+f^{abc}L_\mu^b L_\nu^c\right)^2+\overline{\psi}_Li\gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu-iL_\mu)\psi_L.
\end{equation}
I am stuck with the proof that, upon gauge transforming the fields according to
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\psi_L(x)\to e^{i\omega^a(t,\vec{x})T^a}\psi_L(x)\\
L_k^a(x)\to L_k^a(x)+D_k\omega^a(t,\vec{x}):=L_k^a(x)+(\delta^{ac}\partial_k+f^{abc}L_\mu^b)\omega^c(t,\vec{x}),
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\omega^a$ depends both on space and time, the action becomes
\begin{equation}
\int\text{d}^4x\mathcal{L}-\int\text{d}^4x\partial_0\omega^a(t,\vec{x})G^a(x),
\end{equation}
thus confirming that the Gauss law operator
\begin{equation}
G^a(x):=-\frac{1}{g^2}D^k(\partial_0 L_k(x)^a)+\overline{\psi}_L(x)\gamma^0T^a\psi_L (x)
\end{equation}
is the Noether current associated to the gauge transformation having $\omega^a$ independent of time.
I tried to compute the Noether current varying the action $\delta\int\text{d}^4x\mathcal{L}$, but I could not get near the above result. Has anyone tried to perform this calculation?
